# Preventing Bootstrap delete button click from propagating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I prevent clicks from propagating from my delete button? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to display an image carousel, with the option to click and display the image full-size in a modal dialog, which is triggered by an `onclick` on the slide div.

The problem is that I'm also trying to include a delete button inside the slide div, and the clicks are propagating from the delete button to the containing div- meaning that when you try to delete, it'll pop up the CakePHP "Are you sure?" message, and if you say no, the modal opens instead.

Why isn't `stopPropagation()` working here?

```
<div class="item" onclick="$('show-image').modal('show');" style="background-image:url(blablabla);">
    <div class="carousel-caption" onclick="function handler(event) {event.stopPropagation();}">

    Image caption goes here

    CakePHP framework Javascript delete button goes here (generated in PHP)

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onclick` isn't actually using the function you define within it. You can make it work (on IE9+ and other modern browsers) like this:

```
onclick="event.stopPropagation();"
```

Note that that isn't a function, it's the *contents* of a function.

DOM0 `onXyz` handlers essentially boil down to this:

```
theElement.onclick = function(event) {
    // ...your onclick content here
};
```

So you can see why your code wasn't working:

```
theElement.onclick = function(event) {
    function handler(event) {event.stopPropagation();}
};
```

But as you're using jQuery, your better bet would be to not use `onXyz` attributes at all, and instead hook up your handler in a modern way:

```
$(".carousel-caption").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do your thing here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `stopPropagation` wasn't working in your code is because `onclick="function(e){}"` doesn't do anything, it just declares a function and tosses it away.

Here's what you want as a general solution:

```
<div class="parent" onclick="parentClicked();">
    <div class="child" onclick="event.stopPropagation();childClicked();">
    </div>
</div>
```

`window.event` gets set to the current event being fired, in this case a `MouseEvent` object.